# Excel formula for Euclidean distance

Tags: excel

A former co-worker of mine uses this formula to do some cluster analysis:

```
{=SQRT(SUM(($C3:$F3-$C$11:$F$11)^2))} .
```

He doesn't know why it works.

It's meant to find the distance between some points. When I run the equation without the `{}` it gives me one answer. When I run it with it, I get another.

Distance is normally `A^2+B^2=C^2`. I'm guessing this is doing it for a series of points in the row. Is this basically doing the each point in each of these rows?

I just want to make sure we're not using something stupid.

Comment: the question is not clear, either it test out the given formula or valid cluster analysis ?

Answer (score 18):

It is an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) that takes the squared differences between the corresponding cells, sums those values and takes the square root of the sum. So yes, it is a valid Euclidean distance in R4. Array formulas require hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> at the same time. Otherwise it will return a value for the corresponding row/column.

That formula is equivalent to:

```
=SQRT(SUM((C3-C11)^2, (D3-D11)^2, (E3-E11)^2, (F3-F11)^2)
```

And there is a built-in function [SUMXMY2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMXMY2-function-9d144ac1-4d79-43de-b524-e2ecee23b299) which does the same job:

```
=SQRT(SUMXMY2(C3:F3,C11:F11))
```

Comment: Thank you, @ayhan! I definitely appreciate it. This makes sure I know that I am not using something wacky.

Comment: What are the C11, D11, E11 and F11...? Are these fix values or changing in other cells?

Answer (score 3):

Euclidean Norm of a vector of size 'n' = SQRT(SUMSQ(A1:An))

The SUMSQ function is useful to calculate the Euclidean norm in Excel

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score -1):

```
=SQRT(($I$2-I7)^2+($J$2-J7)^2+($K$2-K7)^2+($L$2-L7)^2+($M$2-M7)^2+($N$2-N7)^2+($O$2-O7)^2)
```

This is my formula to calculate difference between two different rows of numbers